# Shell script to display file systems which uses more than 90% disk usage

Tags: shell-script

```
df -h | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' > sample.txt
while read -r line;
do
echo $line
var1 = $( echo $line | cut -d "%" -f5 )
if [[ ( var1 > 90 ) ]]
then
echo $line sample1.txt
fi
done < sample.txt



main.ksh[6]: var1: not found [No such file or directory] I am getting this error.
```

I need to run this script.

Comment: A simpel solution? `df -h | awk 'NR>1 &&  $5+0 >= 90`  `

Comment: What's your intention with `echo $line sample1.txt`?

Comment: Please review your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ it contains several errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes.

1. You have spaces before and after `=`
2. You compare numbers with `>` you should use `-gt`
3. You use brackets `()` in `if`

Use this way:

```
df -h | awk '{ print $5 , $1 }' > sample.txt
while read -r line;
do
echo $line
var1=$( echo $line | cut -d "%" -f5 )
if [[ "$var1" -gt 90 ]]
then
echo $line sample1.txt
fi
done < sample.txt
```

Comment: Also, concatenating fields with an explicit space in `awk` is not needed if one uses the default `OFS` value. Use of unquoted variable expansions is bad. The output file `sample.txt` seems unneeded. The whole script could be replaced by a one-liner.  No comment on these things?

Comment: @Kusalananda, correct, will add some changes in to the script